# Problems with PHP OOP (PDO)

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am new to PHP OOP so i made a little game in it where you have to guess a number. Now i'm trying to add some score in the database if you get it right.

I have tried many many many things to get it to work but it just doesn't. Also, it doesn't reconize my $db variabel for some reason i don't understand. I have been googling for hours but i can't find it. So please help me out ^^
error i get when i win:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\numbergame\class\game.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\numbergame\class\game.php on line 14
```

DB.php:

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=numbergame', 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

game.php:

```
<?php
include('/DB.php');
class game {

public $rand;
public $num;

public function __construct() {
    $this->rand = mt_rand(1, 2);

}
public function addScore() {
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET score = '1' WHERE name = 'Dieter'";
    $db->execute($sql);
}
public function guess() {
    $this->num = $_POST["num"];
    if($this->num == $this->rand) {
        echo "You won! With the number: ".$this->rand."<br />";
        echo "Added score with 1";
        $this->addScore();
    } else {
        echo "You lose! The number was: 1";
}
}
public function check() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $this->guess();
    } else {
        echo '<form action="index.php" method="POST">';
        echo 'Guess a number between 1-10 <br />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="num" ><br />';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="go!">';
        echo '</form>';
    }
    }



    }

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include("class/game.php");

$NumberGame = new game();
$NumberGame->check();
/* I made this to test if the DB works here. And it does.
$select = "SELECT score FROM user";
$results = $db->query($select);

foreach($results as $row) {
    echo $row['score'].'<br>';
}
*/
?>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: How exactly does the `$db` variable become available in `addScore()`?

Comment: It's variable scope. You're using `$db` inside your class, but it's not defined in there, so you're using a local variable instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging code.

Comment: sorry forgot to include it

Comment: I think this question is absolutely valid..some people here are very strict.

Comment: @tereško if questions about debugging are not allowed then 99% of all questions are off-topic..

Comment: @redreggae: That's because 99% of all question *are* off-topic... "Debug this for me" isn't really a job for an expert. It's the job for your IDE/Compiler.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha but in this specific case it's more than just debugging. You need to know concepts like dependency injection to solve the problem. It's not just the spelling.

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention what the exact problem is, but this is wrong:

```
public function addScore() {
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET score = '1' WHERE name = 'Dieter'";
    $db->execute($sql);
}
```

`$db` is not defined in the scope of your method, see [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1):

In OOP you don't have access to all variables. So you have to pass your `$db` var to the object.

```
protected $_db;

public function __construct($db) {
    $this->_db = $db;
    ...
}

public function addScore() {
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET score = '1' WHERE name = 'Dieter'";
    $this->_db->execute($sql);
}
```

Pass it to the object:

```
include('/DB.php');

$NumberGame = new game($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

If You use include within a class and have something like this in the end:

```
$db = new DB();

class Car
{

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $db->query("SELECT * FROM cars");
    }
}
```

the `$db` variable inside the method `getCars()` is not known at all - it is not on the method (class) scope...

Correct approach (one of many):

```
$db = new DB();

$car = new Car($db);
print_r($car->getCars());
```

while You have something like this:

```
class Car
{

    public function __construct(DB $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cars");
    }
}
```